jQuery().html() containing script tag with type="module" including external js file
When I try to set div content with jQuery("#some-div").html("<app-bysquare>Bla bla bla</app-bysquare><script>alert("OK");<\/script>");, then the alert(); is fired up just fine.
If I try to include external js file that contains just alert(); like this jQuery("#some-div").html("<app-bysquare>Bla bla bla</app-bysquare><script type="text/javascript" src="alert.js"><\/script>");, then it is fired OK.
But if I try to instead include external js file that contains alert(); right after the import lines like this jQuery("#some-div").html("<app-bysquare>Bla bla bla</app-bysquare><script type="module" src="alert.js"><\/script>");, then it is not fired up - why?
As a test, if I remove those 3 lines of import from the external js seen below, then that alert(); would come up, but then, of course, the code itself would not work missing those 3 important lines. :-)
BTW guys, this alert(); is really just a simple example to check if the script is loaded/included or not, BUT in reality that external js file is MODULE that should outputs payment QR code into that dynamically created div of "Bla bla bla" - just to clarify things here as I see you might be mislead in what I am up to here!
If it would help, this is the content of that actual external js file I am trying to make work (all the values are fictional in this example, of course), that is outputting the payment QR code into that app-bysquare:
source link: github.com/xseman/bysquare/
import { CurrencyCode, encode, PaymentOptions } from "https://esm.sh/bysquare@2.7.1/";
import { html, LitElement } from "https://esm.sh/lit@3.0.0/";
import { qrcanvas } from "https://esm.sh/qrcanvas@3.1.2/";

alert();

/**
 * @extends {LitElement}
 */
class Bysquare extends LitElement {
    static properties = {
        _qrstring: { state: true },
        _ammount: { state: true },
        _variable: { state: true },
        _iban: { state: true }
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._qrstring = "";
        this._ammount = 10;
        this._variable = "0026548";
        this._iban = "SK9611000000002918599669";
    }

    firstUpdated() {
        this.#generateQrstring();
    }

    get #canvas() {
        return this.shadowRoot?.querySelector("canvas");
    }

    render() {
        return html`
        <div>
            <canvas
                @click=${this.#setCanvas}
                height="200"
                width="200"
            ></canvas>
        </div>
        `;
    }

    #generateQrstring() {
        alert(_test);
        const qrstring = encode({
            invoiceId: new Date().toLocaleDateString("sk"),
            payments: [
                {
                    type: PaymentOptions.PaymentOrder,
                    amount: this._ammount,
                    bankAccounts: [{ iban: this._iban }],
                    currencyCode: CurrencyCode.EUR,
                    variableSymbol: this._variable,
                    paymentNote: "Some text here"
                }
            ]
        });

        this._qrstring = qrstring;
        this.#setCanvas();
    }

    #setCanvas() {
        if (this.#canvas) {
            const ctx = this.#canvas.getContext("2d");
            if (ctx) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.#canvas.width, this.#canvas.height);
                qrcanvas({
                    data: this._qrstring,
                    canvas: this.#canvas
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

customElements.define("app-bysquare", Bysquare);


??? try to do it unescaped, it won't work...well, at not least here.

Are you getting any error messages in the console?

Although I never do that, I did now, opened Console and there were 2 errors: one was just the fact I was still running that code below that was voted down (removed now from the code) but the second error was that for some reason that external file was not catching another external variable I defined before, which is called just only as another check the file works. I fix that and now IT WORKS. Problem was that originally, that external js file was loaded in the head metatag thus the variable defined was caught OK, but since I am loading it dynamically now, it was broken.

Opening the console should always be the first thing to do when there's a problem with JS in the browser! Way before asking a question on StackOverflow :-)

As I said I am still basically a newbie, still learning important lessons, for some even basic maybe...sorry.

It's an aside, but jQuery doesn't play nice with web components - anything loaded as a module will be async, but jQuery's ready predates that feature by about a decade and isn't aware of it. ready will fire before or after components load based on network. Either your components need to handle when they are connected or you need to await customElements.whenDefined(....

With the help of @Bergi I found out where the problem was: broken external variable called "_test" (it is "funny" as in fact this one is not needed at all for the script itself, read below if you will).
Although I never do that, I did now opened Console in Firefox (F12) and there were 2 errors: one was just the fact I was still running that code below that was voted down (removed now from the code), but the second error was the culprit: some reason that external file was not catching another external variable I defined before, which is called just only as another check that the external js file works. I fix that and now IT WORKS.
Problem was that originally, that external js file was loaded in the head metatag, thus the variable defined was caught OK, but since I changed the way it operates (dynamically via jQuery().html()), it was broken.

Try to append the element, followed by the script:


$('#some-div')
  .append($('<div>', { text: 'Bla bla bla' }))
  .append(`
    <script type="module">
      export const message = 'Hello';
      alert(message);
    <\/script>
  `);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-div"></div>




Sorry, this does not work here for me + the way you written the jQuery part is reported as error in Notepad++ I am using for writing my scripts. Besides: I need to include external js file containing code of a class setting payment QR code into that  with "Bla bla bla" text; the alert(); example I used was just as a check the external js works.

I would use VS Code for editing JavaScript, not Notepad++. The script I have can be a script tag with a src.

Actually, when  I "repair" it making it all in one single line and changing ` for ' and other stuff, there was no longer any error, yet it still does not work for me (please, see my UPDATED post question).

If you are looking to load a script file using jQuery a better way to do it would be
jQuery.getScript(“alert.js”) rather than mutating the html using jQuery(…).html
You can also implement logic in the callback of after the script has been loaded. Like so
jQuery.getScript('alert.js', function() {
   alert(…);
});


Problem is, that external file contains import lines, and as long they are there it does not work no matter what. If I remove them, alert() fires up but then the script itself won't work as it needs those import lines.
